# How to get a previous node of a table cell

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a HTML document and I have some issues.
I have many tables with tr's and td's.
For every tr in tables I have to check the 4th cell. If the content is "fail" then I have to save the content in the third cell.
So my question is....how can I get a connection between 4th and 3rd cell?
I don't know how to get the previous node.

I have tried something like this:

```
var tablesCount=htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='ResultTable']//tr[starts-with(@id,'i__')]//td[4]");  

   String tst = null;`         

  foreach (HtmlNode t in tablesCount){
        tst=t.InnerText;
        if(tst=="fail")
        //and here I don't know how to get the td[3]}
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks like you want `.PreviousSibling`

```
var thirdCellsOnly = tablesCount
    .Where(node => node.InnerText == "fail") // assumes only cell 4 will say this!
    .Select(node => node.PreviousSibling)
    .ToList();
```

The above will yield a `List<HtmlNode>` containing every cell that *precedes* a cell that's found to contain exactly `"fail"` and I chose that structure because of your use of `foreach` which suggests you need to "get" each one of those.

If you need *both* nodes (cell 3 and cell 4) that's a change to how we're calling `.Select` instead.  Here's an example to get you started.

```
var thirdAndFourthCells = tableData
    .Where(node => node.InnerText == "fail")
    .Select(node => new {
        magicalCellThree = node.PreviousSibling,
        proofOfFailure = node
    })
    .ToList();
```

The above examples will give you the nodes themselves but in the comments I see that you're looking perhaps to "display them" meaning ... text?  You've already got access to, and even used in your question, the `.InnerText` property.  Let's select that instead?

```
var thirdAndFourthCells = tableData
    .Where(node => node.InnerText == "fail")
    .Select(node => new {
        magicalCellThree = node.PreviousSibling.InnerText,
        proofOfFailure = node.InnerText
    })
    .ToList();
```

The last example would output, if serialized to json I guess, something like this:

```
[
    {
        magicalCellThree: "000-00-0000",
        proofOfFailure: "fail"
    },
    {
        magicalCellThree: "111-11-1111",
        proofOfFailure: "fail"
    }
]
```

For more information about `HtmlNode.PreviousSibling` please [see the docs here.](https://docs.workflowgen.com/wfgmy/v320/html/32b21d79-a564-1f33-6a82-5e8892ec5fe6.htm)

Comment: I have an error at .Where(t => t.InnerText == "fail"). It says that " A local variable t cannot be declared in this scope...". I have used your instruction in my foreach loop

Comment: Sounds like you've pasted my example, unedited, into your code within the no-longer-necessary `foreach` loop and thus cannot use the variable identifier `t` so I edited the answer to identify the predicates as `node` instead.  Still, you shouldn't need the loop anymore based on the information about your document that's provided in the question.

Comment: I get the idea now. And you are trying to build a list with the content of all 3rd cells?

Comment: Yes.  Edited to reflect that.  We could, alternately, select tuples or some anonymous data structure (like `{ cell3 = node.PreviousSibling, cell4 = node }` or something) if that is what you need.  That sort of thing is more of a question about `.Select` rather than the `.Where` filter we used to locate these objects.

Comment: PreviousSibling gives me HtmlTextNode result if I am trying to display the list...Is it possible to get the content of the node? I am super new to C# and HTMLAgilityPack so pls don't judge :))

Comment: If I am trying to debug step by step the value for my variable is "#text"